# Sympy: possible to make the solver return as soon as a solution is found (before all solutions are found)?

Tags: python, performance, sympy, solver

I'm working on a project whereby I am coding a virtual robot arm. Within the script I generate roughly 1350 targets [x, y, z] for the robot's end-effector and then I use the coordinates to calculate 3 angles for the robot's joints. I'm using **sympy.solve**:

```
def solve_robot(coordinate_x, coordinate_y):

    try:
        w, z = sym.symbols('w, z')

        # Sympy solver cannot handle trig functions that contain a symbolic and a float.
        # Have to round to integer to work around. (Introduces rounding error to calculation).
        angle = round(radians(90))

        eq1 = sym.Eq(60 * sym.sin(w) + 80 * sym.cos(z - angle), coordinate_x)
        eq2 = sym.Eq(37.03 + 60 * sym.cos(w) - 80 * sym.sin(z - angle) - 20, coordinate_y)

        result = sym.solve([eq1, eq2], (w, z))

        if len(result) > 0:                     #
            omega, beta = result[0]             #
            omega = round(degrees(omega), 2)    # If boom 1 angle smaller than -26 degrees then a collision
            if omega < -26.0:                   # with the robot body will occur. Thus, output invalid result.
                result = []                     #

        return result
    except:  # (To handle problems) If solver is unable to solve, return empty.
        return []
```

It takes rougly 7 minutes to complete all calculations. I've tried the flags such as manual=True, simplify=False, but it still takes a long time. Almost all my solutions have 2 solutions, is there a way to force sympy to stop after finding one solution? So theoretically the code will be twice as fast?

Edit:
I needed to round the angle otherwise this error occurs:
**TypeError: can't convert -oo to int**

Comment: try using `nsolve((eq1,eq2),(w,z),(g1,g2))` where `(g1,g2)` are your guesses for the location of the solution. It should not be necessary to round the angles.

Comment: What version of sympy are you using? What are `coordinate_x` and `coordinate_y`? I assigned random numbers to them, the solver computed the solution in less than a second...

Comment: These kinds of reverse kinematics problems are usually solved with Groebner bases. Can you show the general form of the original equations that you need to solve (with complete code including defining all symbols)?

Comment: @Davide_sd i'm using Sympy version 1.8! Coordinate X and Y is the location where the robot's end effector needs to be -> Thus i need angles of the joints.

Comment: @smichr will sympy do the numeric calculations close to those guesses? Because the angles will only ever really be in a range between -26 degrees and + 60 degrees if i'm not mistaken. I needed to round to not get this error: TypeError: can't convert -oo to int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are rounding `radians(90)`. If you want the exact angle 90 degrees in radians then use SymPy's `pi/2`. Here are your equations:

```
from sympy import *

x, y, w, z = symbols('x, y, w, z')

angle = pi/2

eq1 = Eq(60 * sin(w) + 80 * cos(z - angle), x)
eq2 = Eq(37.03 + 60 * cos(w) - 80 * sin(z - angle) - 20, y)

eqs = [eq1, eq2]
```

The `pi/2` naturally simplifies so the equations become:

```
In [17]: eq1
Out[17]: 60⋅sin(w) + 80⋅sin(z) = x

In [18]: eq2
Out[18]: 60⋅cos(w) + 80⋅cos(z) + 17.03 = y
```

We can solve this kind of system using Groebner bases if we convert to polynomials with the substitutions `sw = sin(w)`, `cw = cos(w)` etc.:

```py
In [23]: sw, cw, sz, cz = symbols('sw, cw, sz, cz')

In [24]: rep = {sin(w): sw, cos(w): cw, sin(z): sz, cos(z): cz}

In [25]: eqs2 = [eq.subs(rep) for eq in eqs]

In [26]: eqs2
Out[26]: [60⋅sw + 80⋅sz = x, 60⋅cw + 80⋅cz + 17.03 = y]
```

We now have two equations for four unknowns but we know that we can make new polynomial equations because `sin(x)**2 + cos(x)**2 = 1`:

```
In [27]: eqs3 = eqs2 + [Eq(sz**2 + cz**2, 1), Eq(sw**2 + cw**2, 1)]

In [28]: for eq in eqs3: pprint(eq)
60⋅sw + 80⋅sz = x
60⋅cw + 80⋅cz + 17.03 = y
  2     2    
cz  + sz  = 1
  2     2    
cw  + sw  = 1
```

We are going to compute a Groebner basis but for that it is much better to have exact rational numbers rather than floats:

```
In [30]: eqs4 = [nsimplify(eq) for eq in eqs3]

In [31]: eqs4
Out[31]: 
⎡                                   1703        2     2        2     2    ⎤
⎢60⋅sw + 80⋅sz = x, 60⋅cw + 80⋅cz + ──── = y, cz  + sz  = 1, cw  + sw  = 1⎥
⎣                                   100                                   ⎦
```

Now we can compute a Groebner basis for these polynomials

```
In [35]: gb = groebner(eqs4, [sw, sz, cw, cz])

In [36]: for eq in gb: pprint(eq)
                           2     2                    
   ⎛1703   4⋅y⎞           x     y    1703⋅y   30900209
cz⋅⎜──── - ───⎟ + sw⋅x - ─── + ─── - ────── + ────────
   ⎝ 75     3 ⎠          120   120    6000    1200000 
                         2     2                    
   ⎛    1703⎞           x     y    1703⋅y   30900209
cz⋅⎜y - ────⎟ + sz⋅x - ─── - ─── + ────── - ────────
   ⎝    100 ⎠          160   160    8000    1600000 
     4⋅cz   y    1703
cw + ──── - ── + ────
      3     60   6000
                                      ⎛   2           2    3         2                           ⎞ 
  2 ⎛ 2    2   1703⋅y   2900209⎞      ⎜  x ⋅y   1703⋅x    y    5109⋅y    36700627⋅y   52623055927⎟ 
cz ⋅⎜x  + y  - ────── + ───────⎟ + cz⋅⎜- ──── + ─────── - ── + ─────── - ────────── + ───────────⎟ 
    ⎝            50      10000 ⎠      ⎝   80      8000    80     8000      800000       80000000 ⎠ 

     4     2  2         2               2      4          3             2                          
    x     x ⋅y    1703⋅x ⋅y   97099791⋅x      y     1703⋅y    36700627⋅y    52623055927⋅y   9548229
+ ───── + ───── - ───────── - ─────────── + ───── - ─────── + ─────────── - ───────────── + ───────
  25600   12800     640000     128000000    25600    640000    128000000      6400000000     256000

        
16243681
────────
0000000
```

The final equation is a quadratic in `cz`. The first 3 are linear in `sw`, `sz` and `cw` (although singular at `x=0` which would need to be handled specially). We can therefore compute the solutions like this:

```
In [40]: gb = groebner(eqs4, [sw, sz, cw, cz])

In [41]: [lsol] = linsolve(gb[:-1], [sw, sz, cw])

In [42]: cz1, cz2 = roots(gb[-1], cz)

In [43]: sol1 = lsol.subs(cz, cz1) + (cz1,)

In [44]: sol2 = lsol.subs(cz, cz2) + (cz2,)
```

These two expressions `sol1` and `sol2` are the general form of the solution in terms of the parameters `x` and `y`. You can substitute some particular values for those to get numeric answers:

```
In [49]: sol1.subs({x:100, y:100})
Out[49]: 
⎛704201045    8297⋅√4477025624836319  8297⋅√4477025624836319   984201045   5⋅√4477025624836319   11
⎜────────── - ──────────────────────, ────────────────────── + ──────────, ─────────────────── + ──
⎝1013041254       2026082508000           2701443344000        1350721672       1013041254       20

68551214073  1633183214073   5⋅√4477025624836319⎞
───────────, ───────────── - ───────────────────⎟
26082508000  2701443344000        1350721672    ⎠

In [50]: [s.n(3) for s in sol1.subs({x:100, y:100})]
Out[50]: [0.421, 0.934, 0.907, 0.357]

In [51]: [s.n(3) for s in sol2.subs({x:100, y:100})]
Out[51]: [0.969, 0.523, 0.247, 0.852]
```

Of course these are the answers for `sz` etc but you want `z` itself. We can recover `z` and `w` using `atan2` and then use `lambdify` for faster evaluation:

```py
In [52]: swsol, szsol, cwsol, czsol = sol1

In [54]: zsol = atan2(szsol, czsol)

In [55]: wsol = atan2(swsol, cwsol)

In [56]: f = lambdify((x, y), (zsol, wsol))

In [57]: f(100, 100)
Out[57]: (1.2058759278150635, 0.4346913079154993)

In [58]: %time f(100, 100)
CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 0 ns, total: 0 ns
Wall time: 239 µs
Out[58]: (1.2058759278150635, 0.4346913079154993)

In [59]: %time f(102, 95)
CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 0 ns, total: 0 ns
Wall time: 256 µs
Out[59]: (1.2700124590995348, 0.4406497868037883)
```

Now you can see that the answer for any given `x` and `y` can be computed in less than a millisecond.

In fact you can do all 1350 points in a few milliseconds:

```
In [60]: x = y = np.linspace(50, 100, 1350)

In [61]: %time f(x, y)
CPU times: user 4 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 4 ms
Wall time: 3.41 ms
Out[61]: 
(array([1.82911048, 1.82883992, 1.82856907, ..., 1.20763722, 1.20675767,
        1.20587593]),
 array([-0.47322886, -0.47263842, -0.47204816, ...,  0.43240847,
         0.43354848,  0.43469131]))
```

Comment: wow this is an awesome answer!! Thank you! To my shame i've not really heard of Groebner bases before : 0  I'll study those up!

FYI: if i didn't round the angle I got the following error: 
sympy TypeError: can't convert -oo to int

Comment: The TypeError was a bug that was fixed in SymPy 1.10 (https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/22024). Actually with 1.10 your original code works fine and takes about 2 seconds on my computer. Installing gmpy2 will potentially make things like this faster.